# SFML check for solid between two objects

Tags: c++, object, sfml, detection

I'm still working on a game in C++ with SFML library. I've recently come across a new problem and I can't seem to find a solution. Basically all I need is to check if there is a solid object between my monster and my player in a 2D SFML game. Being solid or not is just a property all my objects get, so that's a simple check, but is there any (easy) way to check if there is such an object between my player and my monster. Also, just the position won't do because solids have dimensions (I need to check if some part of the sprite is in the way rather than just the center). I've really tried a few things already but none of them work, I hope any one can help me out!

Xentro

Comment: What you want to do is probably something called "ray casting". You'll need a reliable way to determine whether a point is within the bounds of your sold, as well.

Comment: You will have to use the dimensions and position of the objects. For example, `if (p.x >= obj.x || p.x <= obj.x + obj.width || /*same things for y pos and height*/ )`